# Detecting the push button outside the loop function in Arduino

Tags: arduino, button, c++

I'm new to Arduinos. I made a simple digital clock with an Arduino, a 2 x 16 LCD, and two push buttons to control the digits in the clock, one on the digital pin 10 to increase the digits of the minutes, and one on digital pin 9 to increase the digits of the hours.

My problem is when I push one of the buttons to change the digits it takes time to do so, about one second.

Is there a method to make the push buttons be detected outside the loop function so whenever I press on one of them it activates instantly?

Here is the code:

```
// include the library code:
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// initialize the library by associating any needed LCD interface pin
// with the arduino pin number it is connected to
const int rs = 12, en = 11, d4 = 5, d5 = 4, d6 = 3, d7 = 2;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

// these constants won't change.  But you can change the size of
// your LCD using them:
const int numRows = 2;
const int numCols = 16;
int button1 = 10;
int button2 = 9;
int buttonState1 = 0;
int buttonState2 = 0;
byte cursor[8] = {
  0b00000,
  0b00100,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00100,
  0b00000
};
String days[7] = {
  "Saturday",
  "Sunday",
  "Monday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday",
  "Thursday",
  "Friday"
};
int secOnes = 0;
int secTens = 3;
int minOnes = 9;
int minTens = 5;
int hOnes = 1;
int hTens = 1;
int dayName = 0;
boolean morning = false;
boolean evening = true;

void setup() {
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  pinMode(button1, INPUT);
  pinMode(button2, INPUT);
  lcd.begin(numCols, numRows);
  lcd.createChar(7, cursor);
}

void loop() {
  buttonState1 = digitalRead(button1);
  buttonState2 = digitalRead(button2);
  secOnes = secOnes + 1;
  if (secOnes == 10) {
    secOnes = 0;
    secTens = secTens + 1;
  }
  if (secTens == 6) {
    secOnes = 0;
    secTens = 0;
    minOnes = minOnes + 1;
  }
  if (minOnes == 10) {
    minOnes = 0;
    minTens = minTens + 1;
  }
  if (minTens == 6) {
    minOnes = 0;
    minTens = 0;
    hOnes = hOnes + 1;
  }
  if (hOnes == 10) {
    hOnes = 0;
    hTens = hTens + 1;
  }
  if (hOnes == 2 && minOnes == 0 && minTens == 0 && secOnes == 0 && secTens == 0) {
    if (evening == true) {
      evening = false;
      morning = true;
      lcd.clear();
      dayName = dayName + 1;
      if(dayName == 7) dayName = 0;
    } else if (morning == true) {
      morning = false;
      evening = true;
    }
  }
  if (hOnes == 3 && hTens == 1) {
    hOnes = 1;
    hTens = 0;
  }
  lcd.setCursor(10, 0);
  lcd.print(secTens);
  lcd.setCursor(11, 0);
  lcd.print(secOnes);
  lcd.setCursor(8, 0);
  lcd.print(minOnes);
  lcd.setCursor(7, 0);
  lcd.print(minTens);
  lcd.setCursor(4, 0);
  lcd.print(hTens);
  lcd.setCursor(5, 0);
  lcd.print(hOnes);
  lcd.setCursor(14, 0);
  if (evening == true) {
    lcd.print("PM");
  } else {
    lcd.print("AM");
  }
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(days[dayName]);
  lcd.setCursor(6, 0);
  lcd.write(7);
  lcd.setCursor(9, 0);
  lcd.write(7);
  delay(500);
  lcd.setCursor(9, 0);
  lcd.print(" ");
  delay(500);
  if (buttonState1 == HIGH) {
    minOnes = minOnes + 1;
  }
  if (buttonState2 == HIGH) {
    hOnes = hOnes + 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Either rewrite the code to get rid of the `delay`s and make sure the loop loops fast enough to pick up and handle the button press quickly, or use an interrupt.

Comment: How fast do you want the digits to increase if you hold the button down?

Comment: A properly debounced switch with interrupt is a good option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`delay()` is generally bad programming except for very simple applications as it ties up the processor.

Use the [elapsedMillis()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/elapsedmillis/) library function instead. In use you will have the following lines:

```
#include <elapsedMillis.h>       // Load the library
elapsedMillis myTimer;           // Create a timer

void loop() {
  ...
  if (myTimer > 2500){           // 2.5 s
    // Do stuff.
    myTimer = 0;                 // Reset the timer.
  }
}
```

The timer is checked on every cycle of the loop so other tasks such as button presses can be detected almost immediately.

You can create as many independent timers as you require in your program with `elapsedMillis myTimer2;` etc.

Comment: And as long as no other library changed the clock rate, it will probably be real milliseconds.

Answer (score 4):

In your code you have the loop() function.  This incorporates all the things you want to do and I see that you have in there the lines:

```
  delay(500);
  lcd.setCursor(9, 0);
  lcd.print(" ");
  delay(500);
```

This is going to limit how quickly the loop executes so that it cannot complete more quickly than 500 mS x 2 or 1 second.

So you are intentionally limiting how quickly you can respond to an external input.  If, for example, the input comes just as the first delay(500) is starting, it's going to be 1000 mS before it can respond to the input.

A couple of options:

1. Setup your pushbutton input so that it on an input that has an interrupt capability.  This includes most of the pins on an Arduino.  Now you can respond to an external input independently of the main loop() function and its delays.
2. Setup one of the timers to generate an interrupt and in your ISR (interrupt service routine) check to see if the button is pushed or not.